# How to transform and combine multiple Graphics3D into one?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, curated-data, chemistry

`ProteinData["A2M", "MoleculePlot"]` gives you a  `Graphics3D` object below.

I'd like to display multiple of these proteins in **a single** `Graphics3D` scene. Is there a way to place the `Graphics3D` object returned by `ProteinData[...]` at a specific location and orientation in another 3D scene?

Alternatively, is there a `ProteinData` API that (I'm somehow missing and) would give me an object that I could place (rotated and translated) in a new `Graphics3D` scene?

[image: protein display]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look to the documentation page of **[Translate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Translate.html?q=Translate&lang=en) > NeatExamples**. This example involves also `Rotate`.

In order to use it on `"MoleculePlot"` you have to extract the `Graphics`' first part (primitives), transform them and wrap with `Graphics3D` again:

```
p1 = ProteinData["A2M", "MoleculePlot"];
p2 = ProteinData["SERPINA1", "MoleculePlot"];

Show[
     p1,
     Graphics3D @ Translate[
        Rotate[First[p2], Pi/8, {1, 1, 0}], 
        {5, 5, 5}
     ]
    ]
```

[image]