# Why is tubed space curve not exported in stl files after rotation?

Tags: export, graphics3d, rotation

Following up a comment on [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121423/changing-coordinates-or-rotating-finished-3d-graphics), as part of some image, I want to make a tubular shape and export it for 3d printing like here:

```
curve = ParametricPlot3D[{a^2, (1 - a)^2, 2*a*(1 - a)}, {a, 0, 1}] /. Line -> (Tube[#, 0.02] &)
Export ["test1.stl", curve]
```

This works.  Now, in a bigger design I need to rotate the curve, so I do this:

```
curve2 = Graphics3D[Rotate[First@Show[curve],ArcCos[1/Sqrt[3]], {1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}]]
Export["test2.stl", curve2]
```

which displays the curve rotated, but export now fails:

```
Export::nodta: "Graphics3D contains no data that can be exported to the \!\(\"STL\"\) format. "
```

and in indeed, in the bigger design the curve is displayed correctly, but on stl export everything but curve is exported.

Comment: My experience is that conversion of `Rotate` and maybe other geometric transformations is not (yet) fully supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised that the first example works. There is an issue with converting [`Tube`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tube.html) objects to [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html) objects, and in fact [`DiscretizeGraphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretizeGraphics.html) fails on `curve1` and `curve2` alike.  You can use the trick from [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119886/9490), to convert to a `MeshRegion` before export as `STL`.

```
<< "http://pastebin.com/raw/FQXgqhn3" (*Import the TubeMesh function from pastebin*)

curve2 = Graphics3D[
   Rotate[First@
     ParametricPlot3D[{a^2, (1 - a)^2, 2*a*(1 - a)}, {a, 0, 1}], 
    ArcCos[1/Sqrt[3]], {1, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}]];
path = First@Cases[Normal@curve2, Line[l_] :> l, Infinity];
tube = TubeMesh[path, 1/50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you still want to combine this with other `Graphics3D` objects, you can extract the polygons, and what you have is just like the original `curve2` from the OP, except that it can be exported to STL easily

```
curve2G3D = 
 Graphics3D[{ColorData[97][1], EdgeForm[None], 
   MeshPrimitives[TubeMesh[path, 1/50], 2]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: [Ahem.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119886) ;)

Comment: @J.M. - Did I choose the wrong piece of code that you wrote?  :-P

Comment: It's application dependent, as always. :) The old one is more general, while the new one, even if only restricted to circular cross sections, is able to produce (`Boundary`)`MeshRegion[]` objects.

Comment: @J.M. - you are definitely right, was just being cheeky.  Glad to see that code, don't know why it isn't being fixed

Comment: OK, thanks.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to combine this TubeMesh with other geometric objects in one stl file...

Comment: @ThomasKahle - See the edit - basically it's a hacky workaround to create something that looks like a `Tube`, but is just the composite polygons

Comment: @JasonB Phantastic, thanks.