# Rotate a RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting, rotation, geometric-transform

I plotted a bunch of regions using RegionPlot3D, and would need to rotate them around an a vector {0,0,1} anchored at point {5,5,5}. I tried RotationTransform, Transformed Region, and changing variables yet nothing seems to work. Any idea?

```
  a=-1 ; b=-1 ; c=-1 ; r=3 ;
  equationsphere=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2-r^2;
  sphere = RegionPlot3D[equationsphere <= 0, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesLabel->{x,y,z}, ImageSize -> {800, 800}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},PlotPoints->50]
  spheresubshape1 = RegionPlot3D[equationsphere <= 0, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, ImageSize -> {800, 800}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},PlotPoints->50];
```

I'd like to rotate spheresubshape1 from {0,0,0} to {10,0,0}, so Pi/2 around the vector {0,0,1} anchored at point {5,5,5}.

Any idea on how I can do this? 
Please that would be super helpful

Comment: This should help: [100025](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100025/5478) or [32468](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32468/5478)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
Show[Graphics3D[
GeometricTransformation[spheresubshape1[[1]], 
RotationTransform[Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}, {5, 5, 5}]]], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
ImageSize -> {800, 800}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: You're a boss! Thank you